# Textarea change on focus

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change attribute of a textarea on focus, but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<textarea name='naziv' id='name'>Naziv</textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
$('textarea#name').focus(function(){
$(this).attr('readonly','readonly');});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PqJdv/)

Comment: You need to add jQuery as well.

Comment: And you should be using `prop('readonly', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code works. In jsFiddle you forgot to tick off the jQuery library.

```
Under Frameworks & Extensions, choose a jQuery version.
```

[Fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PqJdv/1/)

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing.